# sphinx with breathe-doxygen: Display or include text from cpp class description at any place at a rst file

Tags: c++, python-sphinx, doxygen

I have commented my code with doxygen and I want to extract some description from the doxygen docu to directly display it at a place of my choice inside a rst (sphinx) docu.
I use breathe to get doxygen to xml. This works so far.
But I have no idea how do display a description block from doxygen at sphinx:

Here an example:

```
/**
 * \file 
 * \brief This is an example file
 * 
*/

#ifndef EXAMPLE_H_
#define EXAMPLE_H_

/**
 * \class ClExample
 * \brief Short description of example.
 * 
 * Detailed description of ClExample:
 *
 * I want to include/display this detailed description at an rst file.
 * 
 */
class ClExample
{
    public:

    /**
     * \brief Constructor of my example
     * 
     * Constructs a new instance of the example
     * 
    */  
    ClExample();
    
    /**
     * \brief Destructor of my example
    */
    ~ClExample();

    /**
     * \brief Short description of the method
     * 
     * Detailed description 
     * 
    */
    void ExampleMethod();

};

#endif // EXAMPLE_H_
```

How can I display the lines

```
 * Detailed description of ClExample:
 *
 * I want to include/display this detailed description at an rst file.
```

at any place of a rst file?

Example with mydoc.rst:

```
I want to display the text which is imported from a cpp header file written with doxygen docu.

Here is the text:
  .. HaveNoIdeaHowToDoThis:: :cpp:class::`detailedDescription???`
```

Just for clarification:

I know that I can display the whole documentaiton from my cpp file inside a rst like with `.. doxygenclass:: ClExample` but I only want to extract the detailed description block and to display it at any place of my choice surrounded by some other text.